# Liquibase ,Terraform and Spring Boot question

Tags: spring-boot, terraform, amazon-rds, liquibase

I am using terraform to create a RDS  aurora mysql. I connect to it using SpringBoot. My question is on creating the table.
I thought that terraform would create the table, but it looks like that SpringBoot connects to the database and uses liquibase to create the table.
is this correct.
I was hoping to create the tables as I create the database via terraform calling liquibase, But cant find any documentation detailing how to do this,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Database tables should be created by liquibase scripts. To ensure this, you need to configure liquibase with spring boot application by providing database connection details in app config. This means, before liquibase execution, the database must already be created (manually or automated by a process). Then, you will also be able to trigger liquibase execution (by mvn liquibase:update or running the app) within an automated process or pipeline.

A typical liquibase configuration with spring boot may look like this:

application.yaml:

```
spring:   
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/db1
    username: test
    password: test   
  liquibase:
    enabled: true
    change-log: classpath:changelog.xml
```

changelog.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<databaseChangeLog xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
                   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.8.xsd">

    <include file="change-sets/create-table1.xml"/>


</databaseChangeLog>
```

change-sets/create-table1.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<databaseChangeLog xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
                   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.8.xsd">

    <changeSet id="create-table1-ddl" author="bmfirat">
        <createTable tableName="table1">
            <column name="id" type="BIGINT" autoIncrement="true" >
                <constraints primaryKey="true" nullable="false" primaryKeyName="pk_table1"/>
            </column>
            <column name="title" type="varchar(255)">
                <constraints nullable="false" unique="false"/>
            </column>           
            <column name="description" type="varchar(255)">
                <constraints nullable="false" unique="false"/>
            </column>   
        </createTable>
        <rollback>
            <dropTable tableName="table1"/>
        </rollback>
    </changeSet>

</databaseChangeLog>
```

Comment: Thank you very much this worked perfectly. Sorry I did not reply earlier, I was rather ill.

Answer (score 3):

No, terraform does not create database tables for you. How would it know what to do with schema and such? You could a [local-exec provisioner](https://www.terraform.io/language/resources/provisioners/local-exec) maybe, but it does seem like a good fit. You could create a provider to interface with a database maybe. I think what you want is to have terraform create the database, then have your application manage the tables.

Answer (score 2):

Liquibase ensures that what ever the change gone through liquibase is consistent in next run too. It uses two tables while running: DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK DATABASECHANGELOG where xxxLOCK uses to lock the database while running the scripts and DATABASECHANGELOG to track the changes done to the database. It could be table adding, updating columns, inserting data etc.

So all these will run when the SpringBoot app starts. You would need some other mechanism to do what you expect.